# AJAX call not getting triggered on rails 3

Tags: jquery, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a form which looks like this

```
<%= form_tag(suggestions_path, :remote => true, :id=>"suggestpopform") do %>
 <p>
   Subject:<br />
   <%= text_field_tag "subject" %>
 </p>

 <p>
   Feedback or suggestion on anything:<br />
   <%= text_area_tag "description", "", :size=>"50x20" %>
 </p>

 <p>
   <%= submit_tag 'Submit' %>
 </p>
<% end %>
```

this results in calling a create.js.erb

however, since the create action sends an email, there is a delay. So I want to have make the form disappear as soon as the ajax is getting start using ajax:before (or loading) with create.js.erb like this

```
$("#suggestpopform").bind("ajax:before",function() {
    $("#suggestpop").html("Thanks a lot!");
});
```

but no matter what I try, nothing happens.

If however I have in create.js.erb only `$("#suggestpop").html("Thanks a lot!");` it works fine.

How do I work with ajax:before or ajax:loading?

Comment: Your `bind` should work. Is the form in a partial?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the form is in a partial, you should have the following javascript in the *main* html.erb file that renders the partial:

```
$(document).on("ajax:beforeSend", "#suggestpopform", function() {
      $("#suggestpop").html("Thanks a lot!");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The events are triggered on the document, and not in the "#suggestpopform", therefore you need to connect your handle to the document, rather than to the specific form.

the right place to place this code would be in

> app/assets/javascripts/.js.coffee

Additionally the name of the event triggered before sending the request is:

> ajax:beforeSend

This is different from what written in most tutorials and documentations, as it was changed quite recently.

your code, in that file should look something like:

```
$(document).ready(
            -> 
                $(document).on("ajax:beforeSend", (event)->
                    $(event.target).html("Thanks a lot!");
                );
)
```

hope this helps,